# What did Dumbledore see in the sea cave?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, after drinking the potion from the basin Dumbledore starts having hallucinations or nightmares.

Do we know what he saw? Why was he crying?

Comment: His sister, presumably

Comment: The answer is in *Deathly Hallows*, have you read it?

Comment: Expanding on what @George T said: Harry gives his guess on this question when the three speak with Aberforth before returning to Hogwarts. If you have an electronic version, the keyword is “He was never free”, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 32):

**He was seeing (a nightmare version of) the night Ariana died.**

Harry gives his thoughts on this during a discussion with Aberforth in Deathly Hallows (thanks to @chirlu for the keyword, saved me a search!).

> "He was never free," said Harry.
>
> "I beg your pardon?" said Aberforth.
>
> "Never," said Harry.
> "The night that your brother died, he drank a
> potion that drove him out of his mind. He started screaming, pleading
> with someone who wasn't there. '**Don't hurt them, please . . . hurt me
> instead.**' "
>
> Ron and Hermione were staring at Harry. He had never gone
> into details about what had happened on the island on the lake: The
> events that had taken place after he and Dumbledore had returned to
> Hogwarts had eclipsed it so thoroughly.
>
> "**He thought he was back there
> with you and Grindelwald, I know he did**," said Harry, remembering
> Dumbledore whispering, pleading. "**He thought he was watching
> Grindelwald hurting you and Ariana**...It was torture to him, if
> you'd seen him then, you wouldn't say he was free."

If we look at some of what Dumbledore said in Half Blood Prince, this fits pretty correctly.

> "Its all my fault, all my fault," he sobbed. "Please make it stop, I
> know I did wrong, oh please make it stop and I'll never, never again
> ..."
>
> "This will make it stop, Professor," Harry said, his voice
> cracking as he tipped the seventh glass of potion into Dumbledore's
> mouth. Dumbledore began to cower as though invisible torturers
> sur-rounded him; his flailing hand almost knocked the refilled goblet
> from Harry's trembling hands as he moaned, "**Don't hurt them, don't
> hurt them, please, please, its my fault, hurt me instead ..."**

Comment: That's undoubtedly a good reference but it's Harry's guess. He could also have made the thought up to convince Aberforth. Is there anything more definitive (e.g. JKR's interviews)?

Comment: It may be Harry's guess, but it was a guess that JK wrote into the story. It therefore is pretty damn likely to be the answer.

Comment: TBH, I am not convinced that this is what Dumbledore saw. I've always chalked it up to Harry going for an emotional angle with Aberforth. Dumbledore's words in the cave did not fit very well with the scene I had in mind (where three boys duel, pretty evenly if Aberforth was a bit behind, while Ariana watched bewildered) nor do they have enough foreshadowing for Harry's explanation to click in.

Comment: It doesn't quite fit for Harry's character to make something like that up. Granted - he is guessing, but Harry's best guess is likely going to be the answer. Has there ever been a point where Harry made a guess that *didn't* turn out to be true? (according to JKR but not revealed in the books?)

Comment: Skytreader, I don't think he's imagining that he's reliving the duel with Aberforth and Grindelwald. I think rather he's hallucinating it from outside, seeing Grindelwald hurting Ariana and Aberforth, but powerless to do anything about it. IRL, Dumbledore did not look on powerlessly while Grindlewald hurt his family, but in the vision, he did.

Comment: I'd agree with @Jonah here - who says the hallucination has to be a memory of the exact events? Most hallucinations are a warped version of a memory, and a "bad" hallucination is often a nightmare version of it.

Comment: @Skytreader I've edited the answer slightly to reflect my agreement with Jonah - I don't think he was reliving the scene exactly, more like a nightmare version of it where he's powerless to save his family from the consequences of his own arrogance. Also, to back up DoubleDouble - JK pretty consistently points out when Harry is wrong, or lyin g.

Comment: So what would be Dumbledore's "fault"? What he would "never again"?

Comment: @algiogia It's his fault Ariana died. He explicitly blames himself for allowing the whole situation with Grindelwald. He explains this in book 7. "I dreaded beyond all things the knowledge that it had been I who brought about her death, **not merely through my arrogance and stupidity**, but that I actually struck the blow that snuffed out her life."

Comment: I'm referring to "Don't hurt them, it's my fault". It sounds like Dumbledore is trying to justify someone and divert the wrath of the unmentioned enemy to himself.

Comment: @algiogia I realise it doesn't fit perfectly, but he's dreaming/hallucinating - conflating the act (Grindelwald hurting them) with the later guilt (it's my fault) seems pretty fair to me. But if you wish, you could interpret "it's my fault" as "it's my fault we're fighting, I put us in this situation, I'm the one you want".

Comment: I'm with @Jonah, but when he first starts feeling the pain I think he's talking about having to deal with the reputation of the results of what his father did.

Comment: @JonStory Hallucinations a warped version of a memory? And a bad hallucination (all are bad but I guess you added quotes for that reason) is a nightmare version of it? So when someone has a command hallucination e.g. commanding them to kill themselves it's a warped version of memory? That's one common theme but it's not the only. Now if we're talking about visions or some sort of flashback that's entirely different...

Answer (score -2):

Theory: what did Dumbledore see in the cave with Harry?

Harry says this while arguing with Aberforth:

> "The night that your brother died, he drank a potion that drove him out of his mind. He started screaming, pleading with someone who wasn't there. 'Don't hurt them, please. . . hurt me instead." [...]
>
> "He thought he was back there with you and Grindelwald, I know he did," said Harry, remembering Dumbledore whispering, pleading. "He thought he was watching Grindelwald hurting you and Ariana... It was torture to him, if you'd seen him then, you wouldn't say he was free."

Something to note about this dialogue, Harry is speculating as he says, "I know he did". This doesn't outright confirm what Albus saw.

So what if Dumbledore was seeing visions of FUTURE events. I obviously don't know what these visions are exactly, but I would bet they're related to the death of a loved one or a close friend, that he was powerless to prevent as he was already dead. So, when Snape is about to kill him, he pleads for a chance to save whoever was in the vision but Snape assumes this as an act.

Again, this is just my theory. I'm not sure I fully believe it myself.